# Dynamic Checkbox pairs as radio buttons script please

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am looking for a script where I can define 2 cells with checkboxes in where one check box can only be checked at a time

[My Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWkVP.png)

I need the script to be able for me to add and remove pairs of checkbox's when I need to

so in the script I can copy and past a line to add another pair
and then define the cells with lets say A8,D9 and these would toggle true and false

but be able to remove this line if I remove or changing their location

here is my test sheet if you can help

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWfloYTN1PLjohvIGS0UMGQrR2lnZQCNiIN0_Na1ijM/edit#gid=0

[Updated image to try show what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYEDS.png)

just remember these locations may change so i need to update, add or remove the cell locations

I do thank you for your help in advance

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expected as the image?

Comment: I failed to understand the task too.

Comment: So my son is trying to make a story, and as it goes along it will come to 2 choices (checkbox's), of which only one can be true, the issue i have is the 2 choices (checkbox's) can be any where in the spread sheet so i need to be able to change the script to where he puts the checkboxe's for his true false options, dose that help any better ?

Comment: i have added a photo hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can understand `so in the script I can copy and past a line to add another pair and then define the cells with lets say A8,D9 and these would toggle true and false`. But, I cannot understand `but be able to remove this line if I remove or changing their location` and `just remember these locations may change so i need to update, add or remove the cell locations`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work

here is the  answer

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Radio Button Example');

  let range = e.range
  let col = range.columnStart;
  let row = range.rowStart;
  
  let yes = col == 2  && row == 5;
  let no = col == 3  && row == 5;

  if(yes && sheet.getRange(row,col).isChecked()){
    sheet.getRange(5,3).uncheck();
  }
  if(no && sheet.getRange(row,col).isChecked()){
    sheet.getRange(5,2).uncheck();
  }

  let yes1 = col == 5  && row == 11;
  let no1 = col == 8  && row == 5;

  if(yes1 && sheet.getRange(row,col).isChecked()){
    sheet.getRange(5,8).uncheck();
  }
  if(no1 && sheet.getRange(row,col).isChecked()){
    sheet.getRange(11,5).uncheck();
  }

}
```